# HTTP Error 404.0 Not Found - when opening files that contain "#" character

Tags: asp.net

Cannot open .PDF files that contain sharp (#) characters on browser. Example: Visual C# How to Program.pdf.

Code to download book:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" ToolTip="Download book" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("PDFUrl") %>' Text="Download" Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
                        <br />
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" LoginText="Login" runat="server" /> or <a href="../login/register.aspx">register</a> to download book.
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
```

When I click Download, on the new tab it shows:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Answer (score 3):

That is because a `#` has a special meaning in urls. It marks the begin of the hash, usually used to define the anchor in the page where to go to.

You can escape the hash by using `%23` instead.

The easiest way to do that is to call [`UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode((string)Eval("PDFUrl"))
```

Comment: Do I need to remove the `Eval` method because it's showing: System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEndoce(byte[]) has some invalid arguments? Thanks.

Comment: There's still a problem with the url: `http://localhost:52747/books/~%2fPDF%2fVisual+C%23+2012+How+to+Program+(5th+Edition).pdf`. Same error.

Comment: What is the contents of the field and what should the URL be?

Comment: The URL should point to the PDF folder like this: `http://localhost:52747/PDF/jQuery%20in%20Action.pdf`...and it works fine with other files. With `HttpUtility.UrlEncode((string)Eval("PDFUrl"))` it points to the actual page, not to the PDF folder where the book is: `http://localhost:52747/books/~%2fPDF%2fjQuery+in+Action.pdf`

Comment: maybe add Server.MapPath(HttpUtility...)

Answer (score 2):

`#` is a reserved character in the URL specification, so I imagine the URL actually being received by the browser doesn't contain:

```
Visual C# How to Program.pdf
```

but instead just contains:

```
Visual C
```

(Since anything after a hash character is for client-side navigation, I don't think it's even sent to the server.)  Hence the 404 error.

You need to URL-encode your values.  It's been a while since I've used WebForms, but this *might* work:

```
NavigateUrl='<%# HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(Eval("PDFUrl")) %>'
```

Whether or not this works directly in the binding on the page markup, the point remains that you need to URL-encode your URLs.

Comment: Thanks but it's showing an error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(string)' has some invalid arguments.